# Adding x hours to JavaScript date (In ISOString format)

Tags: javascript, date

So I may be looking at this entirely wrong, but essentially I need to add x amount of hours to a JavaScript date which i've done using this function:

```
export function addHoursToDate(hoursFromNow: number = 5)
{
  return new Date(new Date().setTime(new Date().getTime() + (hoursFromNow*60*60*1000)));
}
```

(This is based on an answer I saw on this site as well) and that does work fine, the problem is I need to convert it to this format:

`"2023-10-25T15:00:00.000Z"` (for example) which I understand is the standard date/time format. Usually I use `toIsoString()` problem is when I do that it converts it to UTC.

Essentially I need to be able to add x/y hours/minutes to the date but have it in the datetime format as above? Im sure im missing something obvious but I wanted to see if there was a clean way to do this. But also maybe im thinking about it the wrong way as well.

Comment: The date string you say you want *is* a UTC time; that's what the trailing "Z" means.

Comment: Also you don't need to create so many new Date instances; one will do.

Comment: Adding three hours to the actual Date instance, and getting the specific output format you want, are two separate things. And if there is no method available that directly creates the format you want - then you will have to assemble it from the various date parts yourself.

Comment: Also also you don't need to compute the seconds. You can use `setHours()` with the value from `getHours()` + 3.

Comment: @Pointy That's what I assumed which is what is confusing. I think I may have gotten some things mixed up. Seems like what I need to do is add my hours as UTC.

Comment: No. That is incorrect. Dates are always based internally on an offset from a point in UTC time. Local time is not represented in the internal timestamp value. You need to add the hours via `.setHours()`, and you're done with that part. *Now* you need to decide what API to use to turn your Date into a string. The adding hours task has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @Pointy—adding local hours is not necessarily the same as adding UTC hours where a consequence is crossing a DST boundary, or a period with a different offset.

Comment: @RobG I suppose that's *possible*, but because the basis of a Date instance is always an epoch offset, it's hard to imagine how shifting a date by an hour would not actually do that. I mean, `.setHours()` doesn't really have anything to do with the locale ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivial if the output stays ISO

```js
const addHours = (dateString, hoursToAdd) => {
  const originalDate = new Date(dateString);
  originalDate.setHours(originalDate.getHours() + hoursToAdd);
  return originalDate.toISOString();
};

const result = addHours("2023-10-25T15:00:00.000Z", 3); // Example: Adding 3 hours
console.log(result);
```

From now

```js
const addHoursToLocalTime = (hoursToAdd) => {
  const originalDate = new Date();
  originalDate.setHours(originalDate.getHours() + hoursToAdd);
  return originalDate.toISOString();
};

console.log(new Date().toISOString()); // to show what "now" is in ISO format
const result = addHoursToLocalTime(3); // Example: Adding 3 hours to the current local time
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This might be what I need to do. Since the ending output is UTC.